# Mongoose connect existing DB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I'm trying to understand how MongoDB works.
I created a local MongoDB with the following collection:

```
 db.user.find().pretty()
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a05844833a9b3552ce5cfec"),
    "firstname" : "Emanuel",
    "lastname" : "Mars",
    "username" : "mae",
    "email" : "myEmail@email.ch",
    "passwort" : "mae",
    "role" : 1
}
```

Now, I want to connect to the DB with Express.
The connection works, but I don't get any data.

This is the model I created:

```
var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    firstname: { type: String },
    lastname: { type: String },
    username: { type: String },
    email: { type: String },
    passwort: { type: String },
    role: { type: Number }
}, { collection : 'user' });

module.exports = mongoose.model('user', userSchema);
```

And this is how I want to get all Users in the collection user:

```
var User = require('../../models/user');

User.find({}, function (err, user) {
 console.log('yes', user);
});
```

Upon success, it should handle a login process with users from the MongoDB.

Solved:
I forgot to add the DB name at the end of the connect URL.

Comment: @Dij the output is an empty array

Comment: @Dij Yes, db.once('open', () => {
    console.log('DB is connected');
}); is correctly

Answer (score 0):

```
//server.js
var configDB = require('./config/database.js');

mongoose.connect(configDB.url);
const db = mongoose.connection;

db.on('error', () => {
    console.log('DB connection Error');
});
db.once('open', () => {
    console.log('DB is connected');
});

require('./config/passport')(passport);
```

//user.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const bcrypt   = require('bcrypt-nodejs');

var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    firstname: { type: String },
    lastname: { type: String },
    username: { type: String },
    email: { type: String },
    passwort: { type: String },
    role: { type: Number }
}, { collection : 'user' });


userSchema.methods.generateHash = function(password) {
    return bcrypt.hashSync(password, bcrypt.genSaltSync(8), null);
};

userSchema.methods.validPassword = function(password) {
    return bcrypt.compareSync(password, this.local.password);
};

module.exports = mongoose.model('user', userSchema);
```

Comment: Even if it is an answer to your own question please try to ad some explanation to make it useful to other users.